# Elixir - pattern match on map structure, rather than key

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, I have a list of nested maps, each with the same basic structure - for example:

```
nested_map_list = [
    %{foo: %{test: "Hi"}},
    %{bar: %{test: "Hello"}},
    %{baz: %{test: "Hey"}}
]
```

So they each have a different key in the upper level, but the same key in the nested map. Is there a way that I can iterate over this list so that every iteration accesses the nested map, regardless of the key in the upper level?

To illustrate what I mean, consider this pseudo-code:

```
Enum.each(nested_map_list, fn(%{_key: nested_data}) -> IO.puts nested_data.test end)

> "Hi"
> "Hello"
> "Hey"
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the other answers are both correct, I'd use `for` and pattern matching here like this:

```
iex(1)> nested_map_list = [
...(1)>   %{foo: %{test: "Hi"}},
...(1)>   %{bar: %{test: "Hello"}},
...(1)>   %{baz: %{test: "Hey"}}
...(1)> ]
iex(2)> for x <- nested_map_list, {_, %{test: test}} <- x, do: IO.puts(test)
Hi
Hello
Hey
```

Comment: Surely this solution should be marked as the best answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa `for` is nicer on the eyes, but I always found `reduce` to be simpler to understand what's happening. Plus, `for` is slower. In this case it's a very simple task and if you use both in a map with 10k keys, `for` takes +twice the time. If you do any more complex stuff on the filtering...

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer any proof on “`for` is slower”? It should not be since it surprisingly compiles to a reducer.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, just benchmark them. Is there any way of sending messages/chat here?

Comment: @dogbert Ah yes! I was looking for a way to pattern match this. Didn't realize that `for` would allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum.reduce`, `Enum.each`, and friends are able to iterate on `key=>value` pairs, so in this case I would probably divide this into two functions, one that iterates on the list members, and one that iterates on the map. If you want to store the results (which you usually want), a reduction would be needed instead of `Enum.each`.

```
Enum.each(nested_map_list, fn(element) ->
    Enum.each(element, fn({_k, value}) ->
        IO.inspect(value[:test])
    end)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oooh, well here's one possibility I just sorted out -

```
Enum.each(nested_map_list, fn(nested_data) ->
  [{key, value}] = Map.to_list(nested_data)
  IO.puts value.test
end)
```

Open to any niftier answers.

Comment: For "niftier" solutions, it depends on what you really want to achieve and usually a general like problem won't give you the best answers, because those depend. If you just want to print the values... meh. If you want something that is recursive, able to traverse a map with possible maps inside, etc etc then you might see some niftier answers, or if the maps can have different keys and not only "test", but you want to extract only that, etc. You can extract the functions from the iteration, make them pattern match to accept the iterators, then pattern match the contents.... blablabla

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer you're right, it depends on what my intended outcome is - obviously, the example I provided is a simplification, and so that doesn't really help to clarify what the 'niftiest' solution is. Thanks for your feedback on this question.